# increase efficiency and speed of R function

Tags: r, for-loop

When using R I always have in mind:  "Avoid using loops if possible".  However, I am stuck right now, I haven't been able to figure out a CRANTASTIC way to code what I need.

For the record, after several comments, my statement above is not the right statement, there's no need to avoid loops here to improve the efficiency.

I have two string vectors as input, let us call them, `a` and `b` - they can only contain the letters `"M"`, `"I"` and `"D"`.

```
a = c("M","I","D","D","M","M","M","M","M","M")
b = c("M","M","M","M","M","M","D","M","M")
```

My desired output is:

```
d = c("M","I","D","D","M","M","M","M","I","M","M")
```

The following function gives me such output:

```
my.function <- function(a, b)
{
  nrow.df = length(a) + length(which(b=="D"))
  my.df = data.frame(a = rep(NA, nrow.df),  
                      b = rep(NA, nrow.df), 
                      d = rep(NA, nrow.df))
  my.df$a[1:length(a)] = a
  my.df$b[1:length(b)] = b
  for (i in 1:nrow.df)
  {
    if(my.df$a[i] == "D") {
      my.df$d[i] = "D"
      my.df$b[(i+1):nrow.df] = my.df$b[i:(nrow.df-1)]
    } else if (my.df$b[i] == "D") {
      my.df$d[i] = "I"
      my.df$a[(i+1):nrow.df] = my.df$a[i:(nrow.df-1)]
    } else if (my.df$a[i] == "I") {
      my.df$d[i] = "I"
    } else if (my.df$b[i] == "I") {
      my.df$d[i] = "D"
    } else {
      my.df$d[i] = my.df$a[i]
    }
  }
  return(my.df$d)
}

> d = my.function(a,b)
> d
 [1] "M" "I" "D" "D" "M" "M" "M" "M" "I" "M" "M"
```

The function logic is as follows, whenever there is a `"D"` in `a`, it puts a `"D"` in `d` and shift the vector `b` by 1, and vice versa, whenever there is a `"D"` in `b`, it puts an `"I"` in `d` and shifts `a` by 1.

Next, when there is an `"I"` in `a`, but not a `"D"` in `b`, put an `"I"` in `a`, and vice versa, whenever there is an `"I"` in `b`, and not a `"D"` in `a`, put a `"D"` in `d`.  Otherwise, `d = a`.

It is not a complex function but I am struggling on how to make it R efficient.  I am applying this function millions of times with mclapply so having a fast implementation of such function would save me lots of time.

Do you recommend using Rcpp?  Would it be much faster?  Is there any slow down on communicating R with Cpp millions of time, or it's just auto with Rcpp?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for loop?  The shifting requirement makes this sound like a perfect example of when a for loop is ideal. As for the question of If implementing this in C++ will be faster, yes.

Comment: FWIW, avoiding for loops isn't quite the correct mantra.  Instead, it should be something like: "vectorize when possible and clear. Use a preallocated for loop otherwise."  Which is what you've done!

Comment: Oh just for speed purposes loops are very slow in r

Comment: Since your desired output is a vector anyway, I would *not* make a `data.frame` of `NA` as my first step in my function. Can't you achieve the same just by using vectors to begin with?

Comment: "Oh just for speed purposes loops are very slow in r". No. The correct statement is "Inefficient code _inside_ loops is slow in R."

Comment: @joran, well I should have said, they are slower than C, not necessarily very slow.

Comment: @all, I changed the question regarding the loops since it seems loops is the way to go here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the Rcpp solution, and as expected, it beats the R solution by a lot:

```
rcppFun<-"
CharacterVector fcpp(CharacterVector a,CharacterVector b,int size){
int aSkipped = 0;
int bSkipped = 0;
int asize = a.size();
Rcpp::CharacterVector d(size);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    if(i-aSkipped<asize && a[i-aSkipped][0] == 'D') {
      d[i] = \"D\";
      bSkipped++;
    } else if (b[i-bSkipped][0] == 'D') {
      d[i] = \"I\";
      aSkipped++;
    } else if (a[i-aSkipped][0] == 'I') {
      d[i] = \"I\";
    } else if (b[i-bSkipped][0] == 'I') {
      d[i] = \"D\";
    } else {
      d[i] = a[i-aSkipped];
    }
}
 return d;
}"
require("Rcpp")
fcpp<-cppFunction(rcppFun)

f3<-function(a,b){
  fcpp(a,b,as.integer(length(a)+sum(b=="D")))
}
```

Warning: that function does no parameter checking at all, so if you feed it bad data you can easily get a seg fault.

If you are going to be calling this a lot, Rcpp is definitely the way to go:

```
> with(ab(10),microbenchmark(f(a,b),f3(a,b),f2(a,b),my.function.v(a,b)))
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
             f(a, b) 103.993 107.5155 108.6815 109.7455 178.801   100
            f3(a, b)   7.354   8.1305   8.5575   9.1220  18.014   100
            f2(a, b)  87.081  90.4150  92.2730  94.2585 146.502   100
 my.function.v(a, b)  84.389  86.5140  87.6090  88.8340 109.106   100
> with(ab(100),microbenchmark(f(a,b),f3(a,b),f2(a,b),my.function.v(a,b)))
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min        lq    median        uq      max neval
             f(a, b) 992.082 1018.9850 1032.0180 1071.0690 2784.710   100
            f3(a, b)  12.873   14.3605   14.7370   15.5095   35.582   100
            f2(a, b) 119.396  125.4405  129.3015  134.9915 1909.930   100
 my.function.v(a, b) 769.618  786.7865  802.2920  824.0820  905.737   100
> with(ab(1000),microbenchmark(f(a,b),f3(a,b),f2(a,b),my.function.v(a,b)))
Unit: microseconds
                expr      min        lq     median        uq       max neval
             f(a, b) 9816.295 10065.065 10233.1350 10392.696 12383.373   100
            f3(a, b)   66.057    67.869    83.9075    87.231  1167.086   100
            f2(a, b) 1637.972  1760.258  2667.6985  3138.229 47610.317   100
 my.function.v(a, b) 9692.885 10272.425 10997.2595 11402.602 54315.922   100
> with(ab(10000),microbenchmark(f(a,b),f3(a,b),f2(a,b)))
Unit: microseconds
     expr        min         lq      median          uq        max neval
  f(a, b) 101644.922 103311.678 105185.5955 108342.4960 144620.777   100
 f3(a, b)    607.702    610.039    669.8515    678.1845    785.415   100
 f2(a, b) 221305.641 247952.345 254478.1580 341195.5510 656408.378   100
>
```

Comment: `f` and `f2` are functions given in other answers to this question.

Comment: Oh of course, sorry. Didn't bother scrolling down far enough before posting that. Silly me.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any easy way to avoid a loop here.  However, there is still a more efficient way of doing this.  The problem is that you are actually shifting `a` and `b` every time you come across the character `D`, and shifting a vector like this is an `O(n)` operation, so the running time of this loop would actually be `O(n^2)`.

You can simplify the code and get slightly better performance like this:

```
f<-function(a,b){
 aSkipped<-0
 bSkipped<-0
 d<-rep(0,length(a)+sum(b=="D"))

 for(i in 1:length(d)){

    if(a[i-aSkipped] == "D") {
      d[i] = "D"
      bSkipped<-bSkipped+1
    } else if (b[i-bSkipped] == "D") {
      d[i] = "I"
      aSkipped<-aSkipped+1
    } else if (a[i-aSkipped] == "I") {
      d[i] = "I"
    } else if (b[i-bSkipped] == "I") {
      d[i] = "D"
    } else {
      d[i] = a[i-aSkipped]
    }
  }
  d
}
```

On edit.  You will really see large performance improvements when the input gets big.  For small strings, and not too many "D"s this and Ananda Mahto's solution run in about the same time:

```
> set.seed(123)
> a<-c(sample(c("M","I"),500,T))
> b<-c(sample(c("M","I"),500,T))
> a[sample(500,50)]<-"D"
> b[sample(500,50)]<-"D"
> microbenchmark(f(a,b),my.function.v(a,b))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
             f(a, b) 4.259970 4.324046 4.368018 4.463925 9.694951   100
 my.function.v(a, b) 4.442873 4.497172 4.533196 4.639543 9.901044   100
```

But for strings of length 50000 with 5000 "D"s the difference is substantial:

```
> set.seed(123)
> a<-c(sample(c("M","I"),50000,T))
> b<-c(sample(c("M","I"),50000,T))
> a[sample(50000,5000)]<-"D"
> b[sample(50000,5000)]<-"D"
> system.time(f(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.460   0.000   0.463 
> system.time(my.function.v(a,b))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.056   0.008   7.077
```

Comment: Nicely done, though I think it fails when `b` ends with `"D"`.

Comment: @Aaron good catch, although I think the original implementation has the same problem, so maybe having `b` end with `"D"` is not valid input.  Changing the first `if` statement to `if(i-aSkipped<=length(a) && a[i-aSkipped]=="D)` I think fixes the problem.

Comment: @Aaron, nice catch!  a bug on my end as well

Answer (score 4):

Building on my comment, if speed is one concern, step 1 is to not unnecessarily use `data.frame`s. This answer doesn't address the loop (as others have already said, there is nothing wrong with using a loop in R if it is done properly).

Here is a ***very slightly*** modified version of your function, using `vector`s instead of `data.frame`s to store the data.

```
my.function.v <- function(a, b) {
  nrow.df = length(a) + length(which(b=="D"))
  A <- B <- D <- vector(length = nrow.df)
  A[1:length(a)] = a
  B[1:length(b)] = b
  for (i in 1:nrow.df)
  {
    if(A[i] == "D") {
      D[i] = "D"
      B[(i+1):nrow.df] = B[i:(nrow.df-1)]
    } else if (B[i] == "D") {
      D[i] = "I"
      A[(i+1):nrow.df] = A[i:(nrow.df-1)]
    } else if (A[i] == "I") {
      D[i] = "I"
    } else if (B[i] == "I") {
      D[i] = "D"
    } else {
      D[i] = A[i]
    }
  }
  return(D)
}
```

Notice the relative difference in speed below:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(my.function(a, b), my.function.v(a, b), f(a, b))
# Unit: microseconds
#                 expr      min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#    my.function(a, b) 1448.416 1490.8780 1511.3435 1547.3880 6674.332   100
#  my.function.v(a, b)  157.248  165.8725  171.6475  179.1865  324.722   100
#              f(a, b)  168.874  177.5455  184.8775  193.3455  416.551   100
```

As can be seen, @mrip's function also fares much better than your original function.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of showing how it might be done, it can be done without a loop in R; here's one way.  It's faster when the length is about roughly 1000 or less but slower when larger.  One takeaway is that you surely could speed this up in Rcpp.

```
f2 <- function(a,b) {
  da <- which(a=="D")
  db <- which(b=="D")
  dif <- outer(da, db, `<`) 
  da <- da + rowSums(!dif)
  db <- db + colSums(dif)
  ia <- which(a=="I")  
  ia <- ia + colSums(outer(db, ia, `<`))
  ib <- which(b=="I")
  ib <- ib + colSums(outer(da, ib, `<`))
  out <- rep("M", length(a) + length(db))
  out[da] <- "D"
  out[db] <- "I"
  out[ia] <- "I"
  out[ib] <- "D"
  out
}
```

For generating data

```
ab <- function(N) {
  set.seed(123)
  a<-c(sample(c("M","I"),N,TRUE))
  b<-c(sample(c("M","I"),N,TRUE))
  a[sample(N,N/10)]<-"D"
  b[sample(N,N/10)]<-"D"
  list(a=a,b=b)
}
```

Timings:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> with(ab(10), microbenchmark(my.function.v(a, b), f(a, b), f2(a,b)))
Unit: microseconds
                expr    min       lq   median       uq     max neval
 my.function.v(a, b) 79.102  86.9005  89.3680  93.2410 279.761   100
             f(a, b) 84.334  91.1055  94.1790  98.2645 215.579   100
            f2(a, b) 94.807 101.5405 105.1625 108.9745 226.149   100

> with(ab(100), microbenchmark(my.function.v(a, b), f(a, b), f2(a,b)))
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min       lq  median       uq      max neval
 my.function.v(a, b) 732.849 750.4480 762.906 845.0835 1953.371   100
             f(a, b) 789.380 805.8905 819.022 902.5865 1921.064   100
            f2(a, b) 124.442 129.1450 134.543 137.5910  237.498   100

> with(ab(1000), microbenchmark(my.function.v(a, b), f(a, b), f2(a,b)))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 my.function.v(a, b) 10.146865 10.387144 10.695895 11.123164 13.08263   100
             f(a, b)  7.776286  7.973918  8.266882  8.633563  9.98204   100
            f2(a, b)  1.322295  1.355601  1.385302  1.465469  1.85349   100

> with(ab(10000), microbenchmark(my.function.v(a, b), f(a, b), f2(a,b), times=10))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 my.function.v(a, b) 429.4030 435.00373 439.06706 442.51650 465.00124    10
             f(a, b)  80.7709  83.71715  85.14887  88.02067  89.00047    10
            f2(a, b) 164.7807 170.37608 175.94281 247.78353 251.14653    10
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct?  On my machine, with `ab(10)`, I get a different answer with `f2` while `f` and `my.function.v` return the same thing.

Comment: @mrip: I was sure when I posted it, and thought I'd tested it appropriately. Don't have time right now to check it further, but if someone finds an error and sees how to fix it, feel free to comment or just edit it yourself.  I'll leave as is for now though, as the method, even though it probably wouldn't be preferred, may be of interest to readers even if there's a bug.